# Changing the sort order in a lookup field

Tags: lookup-column, sorting

I'm in an Office 365 SharePoint environment using a custom list.

I have a lookup field that displays the title of courses.  I'd like to sort it by the date of the course, but it sorts only alphabetically by the name of the course.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Microsoft Tech Community forum, and the Microsoft MVP said that the only way to do it is with custom development.